# Possible to programmatically change the value of a range slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `range` `input` on my page and I have been getting reports that it's very hard to interact with on touchscreen devices. My idea was to just create up/down buttons that would increment or decrement the slider instead of dragging the handle to change the value. Unfortunately I can't seem to get this to work, is it possible?

**EDIT: I am dumb.**

Fixed solution below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currValue = $('.range').val();
    if ($(this).hasClass('up') && currValue < 10) {
      currValue++;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('down') && currValue > 0) {
      currValue--;
    }
    console.log(currValue);
    $('.range').val(currValue);
  });
});
```

```css
div.buttons {
  margin-top:20px;
}
  button {
    display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5" step="1" />

<div class="buttons">
  <button class="down">DOWN</button>
  <button class="up">UP</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `currValue + 1` does not increment the variable `currValue`. Try logging it to console to see what it is

Comment: @charlietfl wow, what an amateur mistake by me :( Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the increment value to currValue variable like below

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currValue = $('.range').val();
    if ($(this).hasClass('up') && currValue < 10) {
      currValue = currValue + 1;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('down') && currValue > 0) {
      currValue = currValue - 1;
    }
    $('.range').val(currValue);
  });
});
```

Comment: But value is also a string